# Javascript movecontent from one div to another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the code that actually works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
      function MoveContent() {
          var srcObj = document.getElementById("src");
          var destObj = document.getElementById("dest");
          destObj.value = srcObj.innerHTML;
     }
//]]>
</script>
```

But I need to move content from 2 `div`s which isn't possible using this code.
I don't know `JavaScript`, so what should I add tho this code?
Sorry for bad English, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `jQuery` library. Have you heard of it?
http://jquery.com/

Simple code to accomplish your goal:

```
var srcHtml = $('#src').html();
$('#dest').html(srcHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
destObj.innerHTML = srcObj.innerHTML;
```

`value` is the value of an input element, `innerHTML` is the content of a DIV or other element.

Comment: destObj.value = srcObj.innerHTML;
    destObj2.value = srcObj2.innerHTML;
I wrote this and it worked as I wanted to.

Comment: I thought you wanted to move something from one DIV to another DIV. You're still moving to the value of an input, not moving to a DIV.

Comment: One more question please: I move the content from WHILE and this code moves only the first element of while.. I need to make individual moving of each result from WHILE{}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Both are `div's` rewrite  the following line 
`destObj.value = srcObj.innerHTML;`
as

`destObj.innerHTML= srcObj.innerHTML;`

Since `div` is not having an attribute `value` you cannot copy the content to the destination `div` using value.

Answer (score 0):

Like you get value from one div using

```
var srcObj = document.getElementById("src");
```

get another variable like srcObj2 and store the next div. Concatenate values of two variables and set it to the destObj